# UWP equivalent for PHP mcrypt_encrypt method

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, uwp

I need help to find c# equivalent for PHP mcrypt_encrypt method. I tried to use the Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace for AES CBC encryption, but it isn't possible to use a 8 bytes IV.

Here is my code:

```
var encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;

IBuffer buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strToEncrypt, encoding);

var objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AES_CBC);

// strToEncrypt padding
var padding = 16 - (buffMsg.Length % 16);
if (padding > 0)
{
    var buffWithPadding = new byte[buffMsg.Length + padding];
    buffMsg.ToArray().CopyTo(buffWithPadding, 0);
    buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(buffWithPadding);
}

var key = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(_serverKey);
var iv = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(ivPadding);

IBuffer buffEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(objAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(key), buffMsg, iv);

return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffEncrypt);
```

In the server side, the mcrypt_decrypt method uses a AES 128-bit key (16 bytes) and an initialization vector of 8 bytes. However, with UWP cryptography library it seems IV must have a size of 16 bytes too.

I tried to padding my IV with 8 zero bytes. It "works" but the result is not the same that the mcrypt_encrypt method (of PHP).

Have you any solution to encrypt in AES CBC mode with my 16 bytes key and my 8 bytes IV?

Thanks.
Samuel

Comment: Please show the PHP code with all the necessary input data as well as outputs.

Comment: I can not post AES key and IV on the forum (...). But for sure, I use the same AES key and the same IV. And the mode is CBC.

Comment: Also, the Android (so java) AES class find the same results that the php method. But the problem in UWP is to pass an IV of 8 bytes.

Comment: Android also doesn't support a non-standardly sized IV, so there must be something special about how you're using it. You don't have to add your production key and IV, but you should add similar values.

Comment: Here is a similar AES key : 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
And here a similar IV : 0102030405060708

Comment: If I assume ASCII encoding, then both have a valid length. Whether ASCII encoding is the way to go here depends on the code.

Comment: It's right. I have solved my issue. My method to convert my string key to byte array was wrong. I will share my solution for all. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You don't need to share your solution, because it is not apparent from your question. If you show the fixed code without showing the wrong code, then this does not help future readers at all.

Comment: But I will share also my wrong code

Comment: Ok, but the wrong code should go into the question and not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my issue was in my string to byte array conversion. I used the following method (that you will retrieve on other posts) but it doesn't work in my case:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```

And the correct way is:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexString);
```